# Why do I have to too many re-renders and how I can solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

I need to give the input of a date from my SelectionScreen to a different Screen (ScreenPlanner) to give that to the component
**DayColoumns**.

---

But all screens are already rendered when starting the app so I can not just wait until the user made the input to render the component or whole Screen or can I?
With my Code here I use state to rerender the component with the input data. `prepareData` returns the data for the `Flatlist`.

The data is processed correctly according to my console.logs() but it gives me this error:
*Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
*This error is located at:
in ScreenPlanner (at SceneView.tsx:126)
in StaticContainer
......**
I am not sure why I am in an Infinite loop but  I think its something with the . How can I solve this or is there a better way then using `state`. I tried a something with `await` to wait for the input but it did not work well.

```
const ScreenPlanner = ({ route }) => {
  const [SELECTEDDATE, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

  setSelectedDate(route.params.date);
  console.log(SELECTEDDATE)

  const prepareData = (SELECTEDDATE) => {
    console.log("Date " + SELECTEDDATE);
    let dates = [];
    let data = [];
    let day = new Date(SELECTEDDATE);
    console.log("day " + day);

    let nextDay = new Date(day);
    // next 7 days:
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      dates.push(new Date(nextDay.setDate(day.getDate() + i)));
    }

    const locale = "de-DE";
    let options = {
      weekday: "short",
      year: "numeric",
      month: "long",
      day: "numeric",
    };
    dates.forEach((date) => {
      data.push({
        id: moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
        day: date.toLocaleString(locale, options).substring(0, 3).toUpperCase(), //day: date.toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: "short" })
        number: date.getDate(),
      });
    });

//console.log(data);
    return data;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Header style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{route.params.date}</Text>
      </Header>
      <View style={styles.containerPlanner}>
        <View style={styles.dayColoumns}>
          <FlatList
            horizontal={true}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
            data={prepareData(SELECTEDDATE)}
            renderItem={(itemData) => (
              <DayColoumns
                id={itemData.item.id}
                day={itemData.item.day}
                number={itemData.item.number}
              />
            )}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.containerHourRows}>
          <HourRows />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

I am open for any tipps and help because I am new to React Native.

Comment: `setSelectedDate(route.params.date);` updates state unconditionally within the render.

Answer (score 0):

With your code every time the `ScreenPlanner` is rendered the `setSelectedDate(route.params.date);` is executed which causes another render to the `ScreenPlanner` component...

This should work:

```
const ScreenPlanner = ({ route }) => {
  const [SELECTEDDATE, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

  React.useEffect(() => {

      setSelectedDate(route.params.date);

  }, [route.params.date]);

  console.log(SELECTEDDATE)

...
```

Like this, the code inside `useEffect` is called only when the `route.params.date` changes.

Comment: Yes it works for me. I thought it would be much more complicated x3 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

you call the function outside

setSelectedDate(route.params.date);

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';
```

and used inside the component

```
useEffect(() => {
  setSelectedDate(route.params.date);
  console.log(SELECTEDDATE)
}, []);
```